# ngStorage and Prototypes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been building an Ionic app and just went to implement [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage). This was a great and easy way to simply extend my app and store things that were right on scope. For instance, I went though and everywhere there was a `$scope.listOfThings` I replaced it with `$scope.$storage.listOfThings`.

```
$scope.$storage.listOfThings = new ListOfThings(things);
```

This works great, however that listOfThings has a prototype on it (this is of course simplified for the question):

```
.factory('ListOfThings', function(Task) {

  var ListOfThings = function(things) {
    this.listOfThings = things
  };

  ListOfThings.prototype.addThing = function(thing) {
    this.listOfThings.push(thing);
  };

  return ListOfThings;
});
```

Now when I call the addThing function like I used to (`$scope.$storage.listOfThings.addThing(thing);` I get `$scope.$storage.listOfThings.addThing is not a function`

This makes sense, because the prototype is not stored in the local storage, but what is the solution here? I don't really want to remove the prototypes, and I also don't really want to have to store a $storage version and regular version of listOfThings. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local storage is a persistence model. It suppose to store data and not objects with functions. You should store the data of your list in the local storage and then you retrieve it you should pass it to your factory. Add a method to your factory that will receive the list of things as a paramter. This way you will be able to init your factory with the right data and keep the functions

Comment: Good call and calling out the persistence model. Before anything now, I simply create a new `ListOfThings` from the $storage listOfThings

`$scope.$storage.listOfThings = new ListOfThings($scope.$storage.listOfThings);` Thanks!